# How to prevent "other" domains from accessing URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Node/React application that pulls data from an API.

On the server side (`server.js`) I have an “internal” URL that grabs the data from the API and then returns it as JSON. Like this:

```
server.get('/api/data', (req, res) => {
  Promise.resolve(getAPIData()).then(data => {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    return res.end(serialize(data))
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    return res.end(serialize({}))
  })
})
```

Then on the front-end in React (Next.js) I fetch this JSON with the `example.com/api/data` URL and display it on the page.

My problem is I want to restrict the `example.com/api/data` URL to be accessed only from my domain (which in this case let's say is example.com). I don’t want `someotherdomain.com` to be able to access the same data from the url.

I installed **[helmet](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet)**, but that didn’t quite do what I wanted. CORS didn’t seem to be the answer either.

Is there a standard way to do this?

**Update**:

Here's what I tried to do with CORS. Using this package:
https://github.com/expressjs/cors

```
const cors = require('cors')

...

const corsOptions = {
  origin: (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') ? 'http://localhost:3000' : 'https://example.com',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
}
```

And then on the route:

```
server.get('/api/data', cors(corsOptions), (req, res) => {
  Promise.resolve(getAPIData()).then(data => {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    return res.end(serialize(data))
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    return res.end(serialize({}))
  })
})
```

Comment: Are you trying to make it so that calls to `/api/data` is different based on the `Origin` header? You should avoid doing that unless you have a good reason. It would be better if you made an `/api/data1` and an `/api/data2` and block access to one or the other using CORS.

Comment: No the data doesn't change. I just don't want any domain except for `mydomain.com` to be able to access it.

Comment: CORS should be able to to do that. Why doesn't it work for you? Can you post what you've tried that made you think it's not the answer?

Comment: Added it (and changed `mydomain.com` to `example.com`). SO didn't like mydomain.com with the https

Comment: I should add the way I tested it not working is I pulled the feed directly from `example.com` in another app on a localhost domain.

Comment: This question is kind of vague — I wish I had a more specific problem. But nothing seems to move the needle at all.

Comment: That example works just fine for me. You are using a browser to try to fetch the data right using AJAX, right? Also, I don't think you can stop same origin requests using CORS, either. So, there's no way to stop, for example, another node application or JS code served by the same application by just using CORS. For something like that, you'd probably need something like a user/permission system.

Comment: I was using a separate Node application running on a different URL that accessed the returned JSON via that "secret" URL. It processes the data server-side not client-side. I'm trying to block access this way. I think I may have to use a CSRF or something like that. Thanks for your help!